# passing integer list to the calllistener method

Tags: java, android, jquery, android-listview

Hello i have develop an application containing a list with each row a toggle button a text and an image toggle button status either 1 o 0 is stored in isChk integer list of size = number of contacts ... whenever a contact calls the call listener checks if this contact button is pressed or not from the list and perform an action

everything is running quite fine whenever i close the application the calllistener still picks up the call but does not act according to the set buttons it is reset and perform the default action rather than the needed one

how can i keep my applications array available so when the app is closed and the calllistener function picks up the call it acts accordingly?

this is the button array initialization code

```
 public void onClick(View v) {


                            if(tb.isChecked()){
                                isChk.set(position,1);
                                isChkb.set(position,true);
                                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ring);

                            }else{

                                isChk.set(position,0);
                                isChkb.set(position,false);
                                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.silentr);

                            }
```

and this is the caller function

```
 PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
      public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
      {


              //  React to incoming call.
              number=incomingNumber;
               // If phone ringing
              if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
              {

                  String CallerName = getContactDisplayNameByNumber(number);
                  for (String Curval : myArr){
                      if (Curval.contains(CallerName)){
                          found = true;
                          CallerIndex = (Integer) myArr.indexOf(Curval);

                      }
                    }
                if (found){  
                  if(isChk.get(CallerIndex)==1){

                      mAudioManager.setRingerMode(ringerMode1); 
                  }

                  else{
                     mAudioManager.setRingerMode(ringerMode2); 
                  }     
              }
              }     
              if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
              {mAudioManager.setRingerMode(ringerMode); 
              }
          found = false;    
      }


 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing stuff outside of your app could be what you need for this. Have a look at this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Might be useful.

Comment: after using the getBoolean method to retrieve stored data .. what is the error returned if the boolean array does not exists.... in example : at the first application run

Answer (score 0):

**This is because your settings are not persistent and get lost when app is closed.**
As contact list can vary, Use `database` to store the changes. Check in the database instead of list when call rings.

Comment: i tried that but i couldnt use the getcolumnindex(String string) function inside the caller function :(

Comment: Use a database, use one column to store the contact information and other column for check(true/false).

Comment: yes i tried that but i couldn't retrieve the database data from inside the function callstatelistener every time i try to do that i gives an error of undefined method